# Rails form_for with dropzone.js whole body

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, upload, dropzone.js, form-for

As a beginning developer I'm trying to combine the powers of Rails 4 and Dropzone.js, but I am encountering some problems. I want to create a full-page drag and drop to upload a music file and tried to make the body a custom "dropzone". However, I've to link the Dropzone input to my rails form_for (otherwise it gives me a 403).

The question actually is quite simple: how do I link my custom dropzone to my rails file_field (or I could change my file_field to be a hidden field). that way I can access my dropzone_uploaded_file via normal form_for param access.

The problem with assigning the class 'dropzone' to my element (or the whole form) is that I do not want every input to be 'dropzoned' (just one field) and I don't want to make my input element full_page itself (which works when the dropzone class is added).

So: does anyone know how to link a custom dropzone to a rails form_for field.

Here's my dropzone JS (extremely simple)

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
var dz = new Dropzone(document.body, { // Make the whole body a dropzone
paramName: "imagefile",
url: "/video_uploads", // Set the url
clickable: ".nepbutton", // Define the element that should be used as click trigger to select files.
autoProcessQueue: false
});
```

As you can see here, I'm doing autoProcessQueue: false; I've tried to do dz.processQueue on form submit, but it also doesn't work.

Here's a snippet of my form, to let you understand the whole

```
<%= form_for @video_upload do |f| %>
<%= f.hidden_field :imagefile %>
<%= f.label :title %>
<%= f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control vidtitle', id: 
"vidtitle", placeholder: "Type here", required: true %>
<%= f.label :description %>
<%= f.text_area :description, class: 'form-control', placeholder:
"Type here", cols: 10 %>
<% end %>
```

As you can see, I'm trying to link dropzone to my imagefile, though have no real idea of how to achieve this :p

Thanks a lot in advance! I'll post the answer if I figure it out :)

Cheers,

Wouter

Comment: did you ever figure this out?